# removing target attribute in html using angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, hyperlink

A link is redirecting to a new tab as it has a target="_blank" attribute going on, its dynamically placed there by angularjs in an ng-repeat, how would I be able to remove the target attribute? And for some reason it is the only link exhibiting this kind of behaviour. I was thinking of using some DOM manipulation and removeAttr() in javascript to remove the opening up new tab functionality, however this is really a quick hack so I was wondering if there was a way to go through angularjs to do it. The issue about all this is that the data is fetched using an angular service from a CMS and then deposited using an angular controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.directive('noTarget', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$set('target', null);
    }
  };
});
```

And the usage is

```
<a href="..." target="_blank" no-target>...
```